# Need LINQ to EF Query for my given situation

Tags: linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have to store profiles of farmers. For this I have `MST_FarmerProfile` as main table which contains `personDetails_Id,bankDetails_Id,contactDetails_Id` as foreign keys for storing personal details, bank details and contact Details in different tables.

Now the main thing is whenever i update a record, modified details are saved in same table while previous records are saved in `personal details history, bank details history and contact Details history` tables which again contains `personDetails_Id,bankDetails_Id,contactDetails_Id` respectively as foreign keys. Basically we need to keep trail of updated records. Following is my database schema:

[image: Database schema]

I have tried using joins but the problem is suppose i update same record two times, each history table will contain 2 rows with same foreign key thus my join gives 2X2X2=8 records, whereas i need only 2.

Comment: What are you trying do accomplish?

Comment: As i said, i need to find all the updated records.

Comment: Show where you are at currently with your query, let us see what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this and it worked:

```
List<FarmerDetailsReport> fdr = 

(from fp in RptdataAccess.MST_FarmerProfile 
join pdh in RptdataAccess.PersonalDetailsHistory on fp.personDetails.Id equals pdh.PersonalDetails.Id
join cdh in RptdataAccess.ContactDetailsHistory on fp.contactDetails.Id equals cdh.ContactDetails.Id
join bdh in RptdataAccess.BankDetailsHistory on fp.bankDetails.Id equals bdh.BankDetails.Id 

        select new FarmerDetailsReport 
        {
        FarmerURNNo = fp.URN_No,
        CreatedBy = fp.UserId, 
        CreatedOn = fp.CreatedOn,
        FarmerName = pdh.FarmersName, 
        FatherOrHusbandName = pdh.FatherHusbandName,
        DateofBirth = pdh.DateOfBirth,
        Gender = pdh.IsMale.ToLower() == "yes" ? "Male" : "Female",
        MaritalStatus = pdh.MaritalStatus, 
        Religion = pdh.Religion.ToLower() == "other" ? pdh.otherReligion :  pdh.Religion,     
        TypeofBank = bdh.bankType,
        BankName = bdh.bankName, 
        BranchName = bdh.branchName, 
        BankAccountNo = bdh.bankAccountNo,
        Address1 = cdh.Address1,
        State = cdh.State, 
        District = cdh.District, 
        UpdatedOn = pdh.ChangedOn, 
        UpdatedBy = pdh.ChangedBy
        } ).GroupBy(p => new { p.UpdatedOn }).Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```